# How can i Zoom to source Point while showing Directions in Google Maps in Android.

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions

I am using the Following code....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
+ 35.63508 + "," + -88.83184 + "&daddr="+ destinationLatitude + ","+ destinationLongitude));
```

How can i Zoom to source Point while showing Directions in Google Maps in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to zoom to a particular point on [mapview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView)

In your MapActivity  call **zoomToMyLocation()** and in that function you can specify the latitude and longitude of source point .Here we use [getController](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#getController%28%29) to setzoom();

```
private void zoomToMyLocation() {
            GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = getgetPoint(29.0167, 77.3833);

            if (myLocationGeoPoint != null) {

                    mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationGeoPoint);
                    mapView.getController().setZoom(10);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot determine location",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
            return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
        }
```

**Related Link:**

[Zooming and animating to point mapview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694905/zooming-and-animating-to-point-mapview-android)

**EDIT1**

Refer to this link if you are only using a intent instead of mapview activity
[Android - How to launch Google map intent in android app with certain location, zoom level and marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053352/android-how-to-launch-google-map-intent-in-android-app-with-certain-location)

**EDIT2**

Since intent lets you specify only one point ,you can zoom to only one point.AFAIK you will have to create a MapActivity ,mapview's map controller lets you zoom over a span using

```
mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(lat,lon ,lat1,lon1);
```

Comment: I am not extending from MapActivity as there is no major Functionality,only i need to show the Direction betwwen two points and zoom to source point. Directly i am passing the points through Intent.

Comment: firstly update your question and correctly state your problem and explain what you have used with code .So that people help you .Your question is highly ambigious

Comment: I need to Display the Driving Direction between two GeoPoints and after Displaying the Direction i need to zoom into the Source Point automatically.
For that I have used below Code

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
        + 35.63508 + "," + -88.83184 + "&daddr="
        + destinationLatitude + ","
        + destinationLongitude+"&z=16"));

Comment: Thanks for your post Rachita ..I tried that Link.It is only showing one point at a time. It zooms to that point also nicely but i am unable to show the direction.So i guess it may not work with 2 GeoPoints.

Comment: Since intent lets you specify only one point ,you can zoom to only one point.AFAIK you will have to create a MapActivity ,mapview's map controller lets you zoom over a span using mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(lat,lon ,lat1,lon1);

Comment: Finally Got Solution From Here..
https://doc-14-4s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ods7129k6hp9bjn35rdl2q8tn44p4il6/uc2sn3pnhgcqkbfmtig5epoa8f591qnl/1374552000000/13072187865119303026/04259012655072954194/0B0MdROeR0jbvWVVNUV9jbk1OeEE?e=download&h=14614192385467331438&nonce=gbkbcgrt60o9s&user=04259012655072954194&hash=tp0sks8gkam8a0s4alcms1rt4hte42os

Thanks For all your efforts..